# Android Memory - Declaring Global Variable

Tags: java, android, memory

I use an TextView that changes everytime when I click a button or when closing a certain dialog etc.

Because of that I declared the variable outside of onCreate method.

```
private TextView text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
}
```

In memory heap I've found that TextView is using a lot memory size.

**Question**

Would it be better when I'd declare the variable each time when I need it. Like this. So, what's the best way?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText("Blabla");
}

private void setText(String text) {
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText(text);
}

private void onDismiss...() { // Just an example, I have many methods
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText("cancelled");
    text.setTextSize(32 * scale);
}
```

Comment: yeah the second approach is better. I do that myself.

Comment: you are not declaring a Global Variable but a private one.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if the second approach led to less memory consumption. I would imagine `findViewById()` is simply returning an existing control and does not recreate it or dispose it (when it's out of scope), meaning your first approach and second approach should use the same amount of memory since there's only ever one `TextView` in that layout (with your `R.id.text`) but the first approach will be slightly faster since you've already found and cast the `TextView` once and are reusing the reference instead of doing a lookup.

Comment: That is a field variable, not a global one.

Comment: Don't use second approach, find view by ID is heavy operation and you should avoid it (read about view holder pattern in adapters).

Answer (score 2):

So you need to understand a couple of things.

1. `text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);`

   The above line doesn't mean you are creating a `TextView`. The moment `setContentView()` is encountered, the `views` in your layout are created. That's when the **creation of views** is done and not when you do a `findViewById()`. The above line of code, just gets you a reference to the `TextView` that's already in the memory.
2. Is it OK to call `findViewById()` many times ? If you layout has many many views and the hierarchy is too deep and you are using a `RelativeLayout`, then calling `findViewById()` all the time for the same view is waste of lines of code and cost performance too (very slightly).

So I would suggest you to use `Method 1` that you suggested. This keeps the code neat. `Method 2` in no way will reduce your memory consumption over `Method  1`.

Answer (score 0):

Which is better depends on your necessity. Your application cost can be viewed from different aspects. Like memory cost, computation cost etc.

Now, for memory purpose the second one is better as its not keeping the memory occupied whole time.

But from a computation point of view every time you need to initiate the same thing. Same result but the same work is done again and again. Device need to assign a new memory, send its reference , its removed when done , again assign same thing on another part of memory may be.

So, you should choose which one you are going to sacrifice.